# Account That Was Just Created No Longer Exists in CRM Plugin

Tags: dynamics-crm-online

I'm having something that is occurring intermediately (like <1% of the time), that I have no idea how it is possible.  I have a plugin registered on the Post Operation of the Qualify Lead event, and have overridden the Qualify Button to execute a Qualify Lead request, setting the `CreateAccount`, `CreateContact`, and `CreateOpportunity` values to false.  The plugin then creates the Account, Contact and oppotunity, as well as 4 other potential custom entities.

Below is the relevant code:

```cs
protected override void ExecuteInternal(ExtendedPluginContext context)
{
    var createdEntities = context.GetOutputParameterValue<EntityReferenceCollection>("CreatedEntities");
    var initiatingUser = context.SystemOrganizationService.GetEntity<SystemUser>(context.InitiatingUserId, u => new { u.new_RelatedEmployee, u.FullName });
    var initiatingUserEntityRef = initiatingUser.ToEntityReference();
    var lead = RetrieveLead(context);
    CreateAccount(context, lead, initiatingUserEntityRef, createdEntities);
    CreateContact(context, lead, initiatingUserEntityRef, createdEntities);
    CreateLocation(context, lead, initiatingUser, createdEntities);
    CreateSystemPullJob(context, lead, initiatingUserEntityRef, createdEntities);
    CreateInstallJob(context, lead, initiatingUserEntityRef, createdEntities);
    CreateOpportunity(context, lead, initiatingUserEntityRef, createdEntities);
    CreateOpportunityProducts(context, lead, initiatingUserEntityRef, createdEntities);
    UpdateLead(context, lead, initiatingUser, createdEntities);
}

private static void CreateAccount(ExtendedPluginContext context, XrmLead lead, EntityReference initiatingUser, EntityReferenceCollection createdEntities)
{
    if (lead.CustomerId != null)
    {
        context.Trace("Account already exists for Lead.  Not creating Account.");
        return;
    }

    context.Trace("Creating Account");
    var account = context.SystemOrganizationService.InitializeFrom<Account>(lead.ToEntityReference(), TargetFieldType.ValidForCreate);
    account.OwnerId = initiatingUser;
    account.ModifiedOnBehalfBy = initiatingUser;
    account.CreatedOnBehalfBy = initiatingUser;

    account.Id = context.SystemOrganizationService.CreateWithSupressDuplicateDetection(account);

    lead.CustomerId = account.ToEntityReference();

    createdEntities.Add(account.ToEntityReference());
}

private static void CreateInstallJob(ExtendedPluginContext context,
                                     XrmLead lead,
                                     EntityReference initiatingUser,
                                     EntityReferenceCollection createdEntities)
{
    context.Trace("Creating Install Job");
    var job = context.SystemOrganizationService.InitializeFrom<new_job>(lead.ToEntityReference(), TargetFieldType.ValidForCreate);
    job.new_jobname = "New - Install";
    job.new_CustomerId = lead.CustomerId;
    job.new_LocationId = GetLocation(lead, createdEntities);
    job.new_JobTypeEnum = new_JobType.Installation;
    job.OwnerId = initiatingUser;
    job.ModifiedOnBehalfBy = initiatingUser;
    job.CreatedOnBehalfBy = initiatingUser;

    if (lead.new_PreviousLocationId != null)
    {
        // Set prerequiste job to system pull job
        job.new_PrerequisiteJobId = createdEntities.First(e => e.LogicalName == job.LogicalName);
    }

    job.Id = context.SystemOrganizationService.CreateWithSupressDuplicateDetection(job);

    createdEntities.Add(job.ToEntityReference());
}
```

The account is created, added to the lead.CustomerId, and then used to add the relationship to the location upon creation.

According to the stack trace, the error happens on the Creation of the Install Job, (even though the Contact already was created, and references it as it's ParentCustomerId)

```
Unhandled Exception: System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[[Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault, Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]]: Account With Id = d14241a1-eef1-e611-810e-e0071b6ac161 Does Not ExistDetail: 
<OrganizationServiceFault xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts">
    <ActivityId>05e171b8-60dd-44d5-ba40-42edb79620d8</ActivityId>
    <ErrorCode>-2147220969</ErrorCode>
    <ErrorDetails xmlns:d2p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic" />
    <Message>Account With Id = d14241a1-eef1-e611-810e-e0071b6ac161 Does Not Exist</Message>
    <Timestamp>2017-02-13T13:16:34.5516854Z</Timestamp>
    <ExceptionSource>SdkClient</ExceptionSource>
    <InnerFault>
        <ActivityId>05e171b8-60dd-44d5-ba40-42edb79620d8</ActivityId>
        <ErrorCode>-2147220969</ErrorCode>
        <ErrorDetails xmlns:d3p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic" />
        <Message>Account With Id = d14241a1-eef1-e611-810e-e0071b6ac161 Does Not Exist</Message>
        <Timestamp>2017-02-13T13:16:34.5516854Z</Timestamp>
        <ExceptionSource i:nil="true" />
        <InnerFault i:nil="true" />
        <OriginalException i:nil="true" />
        <TraceText i:nil="true" />
    </InnerFault>
    <OriginalException>System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault]: Account With Id = d14241a1-eef1-e611-810e-e0071b6ac161 Does Not Exist (Fault Detail is equal to Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault).
        at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.OrganizationSdkServiceInternal.Execute(OrganizationRequest request, CorrelationToken correlationToken, CallerOriginToken callerOriginToken, WebServiceType serviceType, Boolean checkAdminMode, ExecutionContext executionContext)
        at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.OrganizationSdkServiceInternal.Execute(OrganizationRequest request, CorrelationToken correlationToken, CallerOriginToken callerOriginToken, WebServiceType serviceType)
        at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.InprocessServiceProxy.ExecuteCore(OrganizationRequest request)
        at Microsoft.Crm.Sandbox.SandboxSdkListener.ExecuteInternal(SandboxCallInfo callInfo, SandboxSdkContext requestContext, String operation, Byte[] serializedRequest, IExecutionContext context, String&amp; primaryEntityName)
        at Microsoft.Crm.Sandbox.SandboxSdkListener.Execute(SandboxCallInfo callInfo, SandboxSdkContext requestContext, String operation, Byte[] serializedRequest) 
        Original SdkErrors: 
    </OriginalException>
    <TraceText>Entered Contoso.Xrm.Lead.Plugins.QualifyLeadLogic.Execute()
        Contoso.Xrm.Lead.Plugins.QualifyLeadLogic.Execute is Executing for Entity: lead, Message: QualifyLead
        Creating Account
        Creating Contact
        Creating Location
        Creating Install Job
        Exception: System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault]: Account With Id = d14241a1-eef1-e611-810e-e0071b6ac161 Does Not Exist (Fault Detail is equal to Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault).

        Server stack trace: 
        at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc&amp; rpc)
        at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
        at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
        at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

        Exception rethrown at [0]: 
        at Microsoft.Crm.Sandbox.SandboxOrganizationService.Execute(String operation, Byte[] serializedRequest, Object sandboxTraceSettingsObj)
        at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr md, Object[] args, Object server, Object[]&amp; outArgs)
        at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg)

        Exception rethrown at [1]: 
        at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
        at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&amp; msgData, Int32 type)
        at Microsoft.Crm.Sandbox.ISandboxOrganizationService.Execute(String operation, Byte[] serializedRequest, Object traceSettings)
        at Microsoft.Crm.Sandbox.SandboxOrganizationServiceWrapper.ExecuteInternal(OrganizationRequest request)
        at DLaB.Xrm.Extensions.CreateWithSupressDuplicateDetection(IOrganizationService service, Entity entity)
        at Contoso.Xrm.Lead.Plugins.QualifyLeadLogic.CreateInstallJob(ExtendedPluginContext context, Lead lead, EntityReference initiatingUser, EntityReferenceCollection createdEntities)
        at Contoso.Xrm.Lead.Plugins.QualifyLeadLogic.ExecuteInternal(ExtendedPluginContext context)
        at DLaB.Xrm.Plugin.GenericPluginHandlerBase`1.ExecuteRegisteredEvent(T context)
        at DLaB.Xrm.Plugin.GenericPluginHandlerBase`1.Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        **** Context Info ****
        Plugin: Contoso.Xrm.Lead.Plugins.QualifyLeadLogic
        * Registered Event *
        Stage: PostOperation
        Message: QualifyLead
        Message Name: QualifyLead
        Entity Logical Name: 
        Execute: Null
        BusinessUnitId: 425821ca-d73c-e411-936d-a45d36fd8134
        CorrelationId: 75366e73-bee1-4154-81a4-354a4c0ffe8f
        Depth: 1
        InitiatingUserId: 995e0b19-4592-e611-80f3-5065f38a4951
        IsInTransaction: True
        IsolationMode: 2
        MessageName: QualifyLead
        Mode: 0
        OperationCreatedOn: 2/13/2017 1:16:32 PM
        OperationId: 68ea91c1-3727-4cb4-a52d-3a632b4239e0
        Organization: org8ea62131(fc3abc92-879c-4a08-8715-4156ce535b92)
        OwningExtension: Contoso.Xrm.Lead.Plugins.QualifyLead: QualifyLead of lead (3d85ff0c-8705-e611-80ee-3863bb36bd38)
        PrimaryEntityId: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
        PrimaryEntityName: lead
        SecondaryEntityName: none
        UserId: 995e0b19-4592-e611-80f3-5065f38a4951
        * Input Parameters *
            Param[CreateAccount]: False
            Param[CreateContact]: False
            Param[CreateOpportunity]: False
            Param[LeadId]: EntityReference { LogicalName: lead, Name: , Id: 122448c6-edf1-e611-810e-e0071b6ac161}
            Param[SourceCampaignId]: EntityReference { LogicalName: campaign, Name: , Id: 330a11ca-4687-e611-80f3-5065f38b21f2}
            Param[Status]: 3
            Param[OpportunityCurrencyId]: 
            Param[OpportunityCustomerId]: 
            Param[ProcessInstanceId]: 
        * Output Parameters *
            Param[CreatedEntities] Entity Reference Collection:
                EntityReference { LogicalName: account, Name: , Id: d14241a1-eef1-e611-810e-e0071b6ac161}
                EntityReference { LogicalName: contact, Name: , Id: dd4241a1-eef1-e611-810e-e0071b6ac161}
                EntityReference { LogicalName: new__location, Name: , Id: e64241a1-eef1-e611-810e-e0071b6ac161}
        PostEntityImages: Empty
        PreEntityImages: Empty
        * Shared Variables *
            Param[ChangedEntityTypes]: System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]:
                [lead, Update]
            Param[Contoso.Xrm.Lead.Plugins.QualifyLeadLogic|QualifyLead|PostOperation|00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000]: 1
        Has Parent Context: False
        Stage: 40
        Exiting Contoso.Xrm.Lead.Plugins.QualifyLeadLogic.Execute()
    </TraceText>
</OrganizationServiceFault>

Server stack trace: 
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
at Microsoft.Crm.Sandbox.ISandboxHost.ExecuteAndReturnTraceInfo(SandboxCallInfo callInfo, SandboxPluginExecutionContext requestContext, Guid pluginAssemblyId, Int32 sourceHash, String assemblyName, Guid pluginTypeId, String pluginTypeName, String pluginConfiguration, String pluginSecureConfig, String assemblyContents, Boolean returnTraceInfo)
at Microsoft.Crm.Sandbox.SandboxPlugin.Execute(SandboxClient client, SandboxCallTracker callTracker, IExecutionContext requestContext, String assemblyContents, Boolean returnTraceInfo)
at Microsoft.Crm.Sandbox.SandboxCodeUnit.Execute(IExecutionContext context)
```

I only see two possibilities, that the account wasn't created to begin with (seems unlikely since the contact creation was successful) or that the account is deleted after contact creation, but before Install Job Creation (but I'm not aware of anywhere that we perform deletions, and I don't think you can have a deletion of an entity in a transaction, from outside the transaction...)

Ideas?

Comment: Side note, I like your context serialization there.  Is that totally custom?

Comment: @Polshgiant it's a single one line call extension method located in DLaB.Xrm.dll (available via nuget DLaB.Xrm.2015/2016) `IExtendedPluginContext.GetContextInfo()`, or `IPluginExecutionContext.ToStringDebug()` (https://github.com/daryllabar/XrmUnitTest/blob/master/DLaB.Xrm.Base/Extensions.cs line 815)

Comment: Does the <1% include all executions or only executions where the lead did not have an account already assigned? I see that conditional but not knowing the business and use cases I don't know how often that occurs.

Comment: Is `job.new_CustomerId` a Lookup to `Account` or is it the new `Customer` data type?

Comment: @nicknow all executions.  Very rarely will account already exist.  Also, the new_customerId is an Account (created be fore the Customer field option)

Comment: Ugh, I was hoping it was a Customer field, that might help explain the race condition - which is what I believe is happening here. Does the contact have a lookup set to the Account?

Comment: The contact's parent field is getting set, could that cause a race condition somehow?

Answer (score 1):

Can you verify that the "missing account id" is the id of the account that was supposedly created?
If you query the db for this account after the error occurred, I guess it gets no hit?
Did you check "double click bug"? Issuing the `QualifyLead` twice "simultaneously" could of course lead to interesting effects, if there is possible `SystemOrganizationService` bleed between the two executions.

Comment: Yes, according to the error log, the account id was the account id that was created.  Querying for it post error returns null, since the transaction was rolled back.  I'll check the double click bug, but I'm not thinking that ill be a factor, since it has alredy been created...  Oh and the SystemOrginzationService is just puling from the plugin context, and can't be shared (Bleed) from another plugin...

Comment: Can you clarify which code line in createinstalljob is causing the exception?

Comment: Yes @keerz, the second to last with the CreateWithSupressDuplicateDetection

Comment: @Daryl. contact/account may have a "special" relationship so to rule this out you may want to try hard coding an existing account guid to see if the install job will create. I have a feeling that although the account create has occurred prior to the install job create, due to transaction stuff it isn't "ready" yet to be used (other than as a parent for the contact). Just an idea that might be worth trying to rule out

Comment: @keerz 99% of the time, this works with no issue.  Not sure hard coding an Account is going to help me validate anything...

Comment: @Daryl my mistake, i didn't see the intermittent bit...will ponder

Comment: That 99% makes me think about bleeding... ;)

Answer (score 0):

(Tried to make this a comment since it's technically not an answer, but it was too long.)

What happens if you comment out creation of the install job?  Does everything else work correctly?  Account gets created?

Another thing to check would be to query for the account after each of your create methods execute.  Would help you narrow down when the account disappears.

Also, in regards to your note about deletions from outside the transaction being prevented, my understanding of how transactions work is as follows.  What you suggest would be true if the delete came from something that creates its own transaction (an async plugin, say).  But if the delete came from some synchronous plugin on create of contact, for example, then that plugin would also be running in the transaction.  If that is true, then it would be allowed to delete the account.

Comment: The contact is able to be created just fine without issue, so the "delete" would occur sometime after it's creation, but before the location creation.  We have no logic that deletes contacts.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer either but too long for comments

So if you're saying it a) happens intermittently and b) there is no other logic that could be deleting the account, I think the only conclusion is for some unknown timing reason, the create of installjob gets ahead of the account being visible to it. No clue why this would happen but again, to narrow things down you could catch the exception and not fail the transaction. This would at least tell you if the account actually did get created ok. If that's the case and the root cause of the timing issue can't be found, you could only try the installjob create if you are sure you can retrieve the account. All workarounds until more elimination of variables can be done.

Another thought is could it be security-related? That account does not exist message may really mean account does not exist for you. Seems odd if the plugin context user created it but maybe other security factors involved?